# How do you remove an event listener that uses "this" in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-events

In JavaScript, for an event handler that needs access to private members and functions, I can rely on the function scope of those to be accessible within my event handler function, and do something like this:

```
theElement.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

and later:

```
theElement.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
```

In TypeScript, I need to use an anonymous function to have `this` be the containing object, like so:

```
theElement.addEventListener("click", (event) => this.onClick(event));
```

In this case, I can't remove the anonymous function from the listening to the event. How do I have an event listener as part of a class (with access to private fields and methods), that I can remove later?

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the anonymous event-listener you're adding. You don't provide enough information to give you a more precise answer. Well you could do `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)` in the constructor, then you can get rid of the anonymous function, and write `theElement.addEventListener("click", this.onClick)`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First, JavaScript and TypeScript behave the exact same way even if you write like that:

```
theElement.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

Second, this is how you can retain a reference to an anonymous function:

```
var f = (event) => this.onClick(event);
theElement.addEventListener("click", f);
// later
theElement.removeEventListener("click", f);
```

If you're dealing with event listeners, there's a useful pattern for your class methods to be bound:

```
class MyClass {
    init(theElement) {
        theElement.addEventListener("click", this.onClick);
        theElement.addEventListener("click", this.onClick2);
    }
    print() {
        console.log("print");
    }
    onClick() {
        this.print() // possible error (`this` is not guaranteed to be MyClass)
    }

    onClick2 = () => {
        this.print() // no error, `this` is guaranteed to be of type MyClass
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that this code will create a separate function `onClick2` for every object of class `MyClass`. That can negatively affect your memory usage, if you create lots of `MyClass` instances and rarely use their `onClick` listeners.

Comment: In this case, what would the type of f be? var f:Function ?

Comment: If your returning function in the case of onClick2 how do you unbind the event. Won't you need the function instance that you used to add the event in the first place?

Comment: @Stewart you're correct, I fixed the typo in the code

Comment: in the example you are showing  you could use static for onClick and onClick2.  If you have a private variable in the class then the addEventListener needs to have this.onClick.bind(this)… And remove won't work.  I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: @MtnManChris this is exactly the reason why I didn't use static for onClick2. As you can see, onClick2 is already bound to the object, so you don't have to bind it again.

Comment: @zlumer using the anonymous  syntax as you have show will work, I've provided an alternative below in the case where someone needs to remove the eventListeners.

Comment: The last code block, `onClick2 = () => { }` isn't valid javascript. At least in ES6?

Answer (score 17):

Already answered question, but IMO the answers here are not well designed regarding to OOP. So, here is my solution:

```
export class MyClass {

  // create member that holds the function reference
  protected clickEventListener: EventListener;      

  // inject the Element
  constructor(protected theElement: Element) {   
    // wrap the class function `onClick` in an arrow function and assign 
    // to the class member `clickEventListener`   
    this.clickEventListener = () => this.onClick(); 
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log("clicked");
  }

  init() {
    // add the event listener to `theElement` and pass only the reference 
    // of `this.clickEventListener` (no braces '()')
    this.theElement.addEventListener("click", this.clickEventListener); 
  }

  destroy() {
    // to remve the event listener also just pass the `clickEventListener` reference
    this.theElement.removeEventListener("click", this.clickEventListener); 
  }

}
```

Comment: I feel like most responses actually missed the mark. This is a very clear and clean solution that worked splendidly for my use cases. There is no obfuscation of details and feels very typescript. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In typescript it is difficult to know what the function call is especially when you "bind" it.  Such as:

HTML

`<a id="One"></a>
 <a id="Two"></a>`

and some code creating two objects

```
let x = new MyClass("I am one", "One");
let y = new MyClass("and I am two", "Two");
```

with MyClass

```
class MyClass {
    private _myInstance: string;
    constructor(ID: string, domID: string) {
        this._myInstance = ID;
        document.getElementById(domID).addEventListener('click', this.print.bind(this));
    }

    public print() {
        console.log(this._myInstance);
    }
}
```

You will correct get "I am one" when clicking on the "One" a element and "and I am two" when clicking on the second a element.

The situation is more difficult with removing.  You need to add a object variable that has the binding included so the my class changes to:

```
class MyClass {
    private _myInstance: string;
    private _myDomID: string;
    private _myFunc = this.print.bind(this);
    constructor(ID: string, domID: string) {
        this._myInstance = ID;
        this._myDomID = domID;
        document.getElementById(domID).addEventListener('click', this._myFunc);
    }

    public print() {
        console.log(this._myInstance);
    }

    public cleanUp() {
        document.getElementById(this._myDomID).removeEventListener('click', this._myFunc);
    }
```

}