# remove EventListener not work after click on element

Tags: javascript, typescript

guys i want remove "mouseenter" event after a element is clicked i did somthing like this but that event will not remove can you please tell me why
im doing that in enter() function check it below ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌  ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌ ‌

typescript:

```
class Rate {
    public stars: any;

    constructor() {
        this.init()
    }

    init() {
        this.stars = document.querySelectorAll("#rating div");
        let self = this;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++) {
            this.stars[i].setAttribute('count', i + 1);
            this.stars[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", this.enter.bind(self));
        }


    }

    enter(elm) {
        this.dochange(elm.target);
        let item = elm.target;
       // console.log(this);
        elm.target.addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = elm.target.getAttribute('count');
            document.removeEventListener("mouseenter",function () {
                alert()
            })
        })
    }


    dochange(el) {

        for (let i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++) {
            //  console.log(el.stars[i].getAttribute("count"))
            if (this.stars[i].getAttribute("count") > el.getAttribute("count")) {
                this.stars[i].classList.remove("fill")
            } else {

                this.stars[i].classList.add("fill")
            }
        }
    }
}

let obj = new Rate();
```

compiled js :

```
var Rate = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Rate() {
        this.init();
    }
    Rate.prototype.init = function () {
        this.stars = document.querySelectorAll("#rating div");
        var self = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++) {
            this.stars[i].setAttribute('count', i + 1);
            this.stars[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", this.enter.bind(self));
        }
    };
    Rate.prototype.enter = function (elm) {
        this.dochange(elm.target);
        var item = elm.target;
        // console.log(this);
        elm.target.addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = elm.target.getAttribute('count');
            document.removeEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
                alert();
            });
        });
    };
    Rate.prototype.dochange = function (el) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++) {
            //  console.log(el.stars[i].getAttribute("count"))
            if (this.stars[i].getAttribute("count") > el.getAttribute("count")) {
                this.stars[i].classList.remove("fill");
            }
            else {
                this.stars[i].classList.add("fill");
            }
        }
    };
    return Rate;
}());
var obj = new Rate();
```

Comment: This might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023688/how-do-you-remove-an-event-listener-that-uses-this-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using removeEventListener as it should be (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

First, you cannot add the listener to a `div` and after, remove it from `document`. You should call `removeEventListener` on the element where you called `addEventListener` = **this.stars[i]**.

Then, an element may have several listener for the same event type, you have to specify which listener that you want to remove.
The second parameter of `removeEventListener` should be the same reference to the listener that was addded = **this.enter**.

```
this.stars[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", this.enter);
this.stars[i].removeEventListener("mouseenter", this.enter);
```

Comment: and if you want to use the bound function then first create a reference: private enterRef; this.enterRef = this.enter.bind(this); and then use this.enterRef in the addEventListener and the removeEventListener.